# Hangfire recurring job says it runs successfully, but the method is never actually called

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

I have a recurring job set to run every 5 minutes. In the Hangfire dashboard, it says it runs successfully, however the method attached to the job doesn't get fired, and the action it is supposed to perform doesn't happen. However, if I go in an manually re-queue one of the tasks, it will run properly. Any thoughts?

Adding the job.

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
app.UseHangfireServer();
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => timerScheduledTask(), Cron.MinuteInterval(5));
```

Method that should be called.

```
public void timerScheduledTask()
{
    IndeedXmlParser indeed = new IndeedXmlParser();
    indeed.generateXml();
}
```

I know that the generateXml() method works, as it is used successfully elsewhere.

It should go in to the timerScheduledTask method, and then in to the generateXml method, but it doesn't.